# How to Block DIV Resource from Loading on Page?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, wordpress, dom-events

I am editing a WordPress PHP page and I want the page to block a particular external script from loading `<div class="count_box">`

Here is the script:

```
<script>
    (function(document,script,id)
    {
         var js,
             r=document.getElementsByTagName(script)[0],
             protocol=/^http:/.test(document.location)?'http':'https';
        if(!document.getElementById(id))
        {
           js=document.createElement(script);
           js.id=id;js.src=protocol+'://widgets.changetip.com/public/js/widgets.js';r.parentNode.insertBefore(js,r)
        }
     }(document,'script','changetip_w_0'));
</script>
```

Is there a way I can affect this script to not load count_box? Or put in a script immediately after which blocks `<div class="count_box">`?

Comment: Where and when is the script being "enqueued"?

Comment: What exactly does that mean? The script comes in near the end of the page, but it would seem possible to put a script after it blocking the DIV from displaying.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know how it's being loaded without seeing any php. It looks like a widget called "changetip" from the code provided. Maybe temporarily deactivate it and see if that is causing it.

If that isn't it, check `header.php` and `footer.php` in your themes directory found in `/wordpress/wp-content/themes/yourThemeName` It will probably reveal itself somewhere in there.

Comment: It's being loaded by a script and I know where it is located. I simply want to block one element it is producing.

Comment: Im not convinced this script is actually loading the count_box div. it is probably happening inside of `widgets.js`, which is being inserted just before the first script tag from a third party URL. This chrome extension can help show exactly what event handler is bound to that div. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/visual-event/pbmmieigblcbldgdokdjpioljjninaim?hl=en-US

You could always use CSS to hide that div, or some simple jquery to `.remove()` it.

Comment: Can you give me an idea on how to implement a jquery .remove() or change the CSS to display:none

Comment: `.count_box {display:none;}`   or   `$(function(){ $('.count_box').remove(); })`

I would recommend the CSS way. This is also assuming its a class and not an id. You will have to look up the difference.

Comment: This is what I am trying `<script>$(function(){ $('count_box').remove(); })</script>` and its not having any effect on the page. The class is count_box and I have tried div.count_box and .count_box as well.

Comment: or vanilla js `<script>var elem = document.getElementsByClassName('count_box');  if (elem.parentNode) {
elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
} </script>`   It will have to be after that script so you have access to it in the DOM. Also, you should try researching how to do this. People on SO won't write code for you like I am.

Comment: you have to include jQuery in the header or footer if you want to use it.